# Coloring a dynamic label for an Android app

Tags: android, delphi, fonts

I want to change the color of one of the labels I create dynamically into red. But it does not (seem) to work. Does anyone have an idea how to fix this problem?

The piece of the code I use:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  H: byte;
begin
  //T := Screen.Size.Height;
  Label1.Text := 'scherm hoogte is genoegz ';// +IntToStr(T);
  Label1.Font.Style := Label1.Font.Style + [TFontStyle.fsBold];
  T := Screen.Size.Width;
  Label2.Font.Style := Label2.Font.Style + [TFontStyle.fsUnderline];
  Label2.Font.Style := Label2.Font.Style + [TFontStyle.fsItalic];
  Label2.TextSettings.FontColor :=   TAlphaColors.Yellowgreen; //$FFFF0000;//clRed; //$FF0000FF;
  Label2.Text := 'scherm breedte is ' + IntToStr(T);

  for H := 0 to 6 do
  begin
    DagLabel[H] := TLabel.Create(Self);
    with DagLabel[H] do
    begin
      Parent := Form1;
      Position.X := H * (T div 6) + 25;
      Position.Y := 50;
      Font.Style := [TFontStyle.fsBold];
      //TextSettings.FontColor := TAlphaColors.Yellowgreen;//does not work here eighter
      case H of
        0 : Begin
          Text := 'Zondag';
          TextSettings.FontColor := TAlphaColors.Red;
        end;
        1 : Text := 'Maandag';
        2 : Text := 'Dinsdag';
        3 : Text := 'Woensdag';
        4 : Text := 'Donderdag';
        5 : Text := 'Vrijdag';
        else
          Text := 'Zaterdag';
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried assigning the new colour value to Font instead of TextSettings?

`label2.Font.Color := $00000000`

Comment: thats not the way to acces the color in a firemonkey aplication. Does not work but thanx Nick

Comment: Oops. In that case it seems that `StyledSettings` property is overriding your changes - i.e. check to see if `ssFontColor` is in the enum. I don't have much experience with FireMonkey though.

Comment: Quote: Remember that when you are changing the value of a property (for example of the TextSettings.FontColor property), then the actual changing of the control's view happens only if the StyledSettings property does not contain the TStyledSetting.ssFontColor constant. The following table shows which TStyledSetting constants control handling of which TTextSettings text representation properties.

Comment: Nick i can't see the table, and do you mean i have to "free" the color of the label first ?

Comment: Nope, if the ffFontColor is set on StyledSettings, then TextSettings.FontColor will be ignored, full reference here: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/FMX.Types.ITextSettings

Comment: Sorry i tried to understand the reference but can't find the solution to color my labels. Can you post a small example code, it is hard to find a simple example on the internet.

Comment: You can test it by removing all styled settings, something like this: `label2.StyledSettings = []` then setting `TextSettings.FontColor` should work